# Flat universe a torus?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, observable-universe

As shown by cosmologists space is presumably a flat expanse. In his book the *Fabric of the Cosmos*, Brian Greene shows that one of the possible shapes of this flat universe is a Torus.
My question is, are there other shapes that would fulfill the same criteria, if so, how?

Comment: Anything homeomorphic to a torus would fulfill the criteria

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: A coffee cup. Or at least the shape of one

Comment: Does a coffee cup shape qualify as flat space?

Comment: @Jaywalker It can - it is continuously deformable into a torus. You could take a [flat torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus) and continuously deform it into a coffee cup shape, without losing flatness - a flat coffee cup I guess.

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a nice description of this area in the [Wikipedia article on the shape of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe). As well as the torus possible shapes include the [Poincaré dodecahedral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Cosmology) and the [Picard horn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_horn).

Googling will find you [lots of stuff about the duodecahedral shape](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=universe%20duodecahedron), and despite its potential for causing sniggers there is quite a bit [on Picard's horn as well](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=universe%20picard%20horn).

Comment: The OP mentioned "flat" topologies, though. As far as I know, those two other examples, the Poincaré dodecahedral space and the Picard horn are actually not flat, but positively and negatively curved, respectively. A Klein bottle and its higher-dimensional cousins are flat, I believe.